# Add Asset library app to personal website possible?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

I'd like to add an asset library app to my personal "/my" Sharepoint Website.
Unfortunately, only the document-library, an access-app and the spreadsheet-import apps are available.
What must be done to add the asset library?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I tjink asset library is only available with publishing feature which typically is not on a my site.

Comment: have you enabled enterprise features?

Comment: Brian, you're right. I had to enable Sharepoint Publishing Infrastructure on the site. Now I can add an asset-library. Thanks! (post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think asset library is only available with the Publishing Features, which typically are not turned on within a My Site.